# Mocked class method only returns undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm testing a React class component which relies on a service for retrieving the user auth.

```js
  async populateState() {
    const result = await authService.getUserAuthenticationStatus();
    const { user, isAuthenticated } = result;
    this.setState({
      isAuthenticated,
      user
    });
  }
```

So, I would like to mock the return value for `getUserAuthenticationStatus` like so:

```js
jest.mock('./components/api-authorization/AuthorizeService');

beforeAll(() => {
  jest.spyOn(AuthService, 'getUserAuthenticationStatus').mockReturnValue(
    Promise.resolve({
      isAuthenticated: true,
      user: {}
    })
  );
});
```

The problem here, is that when running my tests, the method keeps returning `undefined` rather than the mock value I had set up in my test. If we take a quick look at the exported member, we can see the class is being instantiated and then exported. Could this be the issue?

```js
const authService = new AuthorizeService();
export default authService;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `jest.mock` is unnecessary here. You can simply spyOn the method since you already have an instance.

```js
beforeAll(() => {
  jest.spyOn(authService, 'getUserAuthenticationStatus')
    // Returns promise no need to add manually
    .mockResolvedValue({ isAuthenticated: true, user: {} });
});

// And make sure you clear the mocks in the end. 
afterAll(() => jest.clearAllMocks());
```

**Note**: you are spying on the `authService`, not the `AuthService`

Comment: I'm still receiving `undefined`, I managed to get these tests working by rendering the components directly instead of relying on the app's navigation. I will visit this later on using React Testing Library rather than enzyme

Comment: If you show more context would be helpful, like your test run where it fails